# Unable to initialize the Context

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-context

I have an activity which uses an adapter and a fragment that displays a recycler list view. When the user taps on any row, I display an AlertDialog (created as a DialogFragment) for them to enter the data.

The callbacks from the AlertDialog is listened by the Fragment and once all the fields are captured in the Fragment, the completed object is sent back to the activity to save it in the database.

Here is a screenshot ...

[image]

Right now after I enter a name and hit continue, I get a crash because the listener from the DisplayTextEntryAlert class (i.e. DialogFragment) isn't initialized.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void alerts.DisplayTextEntryAlert$DisplayTextEntryAlertListener.onYesButtonClicked(android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at alerts.DisplayTextEntryAlert$1.onClick(DisplayTextEntryAlert.java:97)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:161)
```

In my DisplayTextEntryAlert class, it crashes when mListener.onYesButtonClicked is executed.

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    ....
    ....
    ....
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.stgContinue, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
             mTextEntered = editTextControl.getText().toString();
             mListener.onYesButtonClicked(DisplayTextEntryAlert.this, mTextEntered);
        }
    });
```

The mListener object is initialized in the 'onAttach' method in the DisplayTextEntryAlert class

```
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof DisplayTextEntryAlertListener) {
        mListener = (DisplayTextEntryAlertListener)context;
    } else {
        Log.d(this.toString(),"trackContext");
        Log.d(this.toString(),context.toString());
        //throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement DisplayTextEntryAlertListener");
    }
}
```

But when debugging, I notice that this line never gets executed.

```
mListener = (DisplayTextEntryAlertListener)context;
```

This AlertDialog is created from the Fragment class (AddFriendFragment) that is launched from the activity (AddFriendActivity)

```
DisplayTextEntryAlert displayTextEntryAlertFragment = DisplayTextEntryAlert.newInstance("","Enter the first name");
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();
displayTextEntryAlertFragment.show(fragmentManager, "newFriendFragment"); // give it a name for retrieving
```

The 'mContext' in here is created from the onCreateView method in this fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_newfriend_list, container, false);

    // Set the adapter
    if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
        mContext = view.getContext();
        ....
        ....
        ....
        mNewFriendAdapter = new NewFriendAdapter(mNewFriendFields, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mNewFriendAdapter);
    }
    return view;
}
```

Question: I'm clearly missing something here else the mListener would have been initialized in the onAttach method in the DisplayTextEntryAlert class.

Any clues ?

Here is the full source code for reference
https://gist.github.com/ArdenDev/229c69f803dce62a1e46acb0e05c7f1a

Comment: You can try to change `DisplayTextEntryAlert.this` to `getActivity()` in `onYesButtonClicked`'s parameter

Comment: @KeLiuyue no that won't work. The argument needs to be a DialogFragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the trick was to use setFragment. This now works

```
DisplayTextEntryAlert displayTextEntryAlertFragment = DisplayTextEntryAlert.newInstance("","Enter the first name");
displayTextEntryAlertFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
displayTextEntryAlertFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "newFriendFragment");
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your `AddFriendActivity` implement `DisplayTextEntryAlertListener`

Then override that functionality in `AddFriendActivity`

```
@Override
public void onYesButtonClicked(String text)
{
    // Do anything with your text
}
```

If you need `Context` for `Listener`, use `getActivity()` or `getContext()` instead of `DisplayTextEntryAlert.this`

```
mListener.onYesButtonClicked(getActivity());
```

One more thing, you don't have to check `instance of` when inflating your view. Because I saw there is not only `RecyclerView` in your layout, but also `ToolBar`, so the view is definately not `RecyclerView`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_newfriend_list, container, false);

// Remove the instance of condition
mContext = view.getContext();
    ....
    ....
    ....
    mNewFriendAdapter = new NewFriendAdapter(mNewFriendFields, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mNewFriendAdapter);
return view;
}
```

Comment: I don't need the callback to be sent to the activity. I would like to handle this inside the AddFriendFragment itself.

Comment: Please take a look at the source code gist link. I would like the entire Person object to be sent to the activity once the user has entered all the fields.

Answer (score 0):

So, your problem that you use on onAttach(Content context) which was added in 23 API version (Android 6) and it never calls at lower API versions. You should override both onAttach(Context context) and onAttach(Activity activity)

Comment: Just started Android coding few weeks ago. Could you give me some context on what should be in the override ?

Comment: @ArdenDev just dublicate code you have in onAttach (Context context) to onAttach (Activity activity)

Comment: if I do that, it expects me to implement DisplayTextEntryAlertListener in AddFriendActivity. I would like to handle the callback inside AddFriendFragment.

Comment: @ArdenDev you can create a public method in activity, which will return  your fragment. And in onAttach, you cast activity to YouActivityName, call method and cast the result it to your listener.